# How to invert characters in a Vector in R language?

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, vector

I'm a beginner, exploring R language. Was working on below data.frame and I would like to invert the Sex vector values. i.e 'F' -> 'M' and 'M' -> 'F'

```
sampleData
         Age Height Sex
Alex      25    177   F
Lilly     31    163   F
Mark      23    190   M
Oliver    52    179   M
Martha    76    163   F
Lucas     49    183   M
Caroline  26    164   F
```

I tried three ways but couldn't hit the right approach.

1. Replaced F with M and vice-versa, but wouldn't affect the actual values in the Vector.

   levels(Sex)[1] <- "F"
   levels(Sex)[2] <- "M"
2. Tried below using 'mapvalues' function but still no changes.

   library(plyr)
   mapvalues(sampleData$Sex, from = c("F", "M"), to = c("M", "F"))
3. Converted Sex to a matrix and applied 'solve', but learnt it can be applied only on numeric matrix.

   Sex <- as.matrix(Sex)
   solve(sampleData$Sex)

Could someone please assist me on resolving the character inversion ?!

Comment: `df$Sex <- chartr('FM', 'MF', df$Sex)`

Comment: `factor(df$Sex, levels = c("F","M"), labels = c("M", "F"))`

Comment: Thank you @Sotos and docendo. Both worked perfect. But, Sotos could you please provide me insights on chartr function's working ?! It was so very useful.

Comment: If you go to the help page `?chartr` It is very clear about what it does. You basically feed it the old string and the new string and it switches them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simply the statement `ifelse` like this.

For simplicity I have created a similar data frame:

```
sampleData <- data.frame(Age = c(25,31,23,15), Height = c(177,163,190,163), Sex = c("M","F","F","M"))
```

And then you can use `ifelse`

```
sampleData$Sex <- ifelse(sampleData$Sex=="F","M","F")
```

Comment: @PradeepVaranasi no problem! So now accept my answer! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You could also write a function to convert it:

```
convertChar <- function(vec){
    if(length(unique(vec))!=2)
        stop("Vector has more or less than 2 unique values")
    newChar <- ifelse(vec == unique(vec)[1],unique(vec)[2],unique(vec)[1])
    return(newChar)
}

convertChar(c("M","M","F","F"))
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my query. But considering LOC & re-usability, above answer and the one in comments are easy.